# Why does the error "expression is not acceptable" appear?

Tags: c, conditional-operator

```
(a > b) ? c = 10 : (a < b) ? c = 20 : c = 30;
```

why this code make a error that called "***expression is not acceptable***" ??

Error messages said "c = 30" this part made the error.

Comment: I advise you to avoid nesting conditional operators. It's confusing.

Comment: Indeed code like this is not acceptable, regardless of if you get it compiling or not. Write this with if statements and all problems will go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because ternary operator `?:` has precedence over `=`, the expression is parsed as:

```
((a > b) ? c = 10 : (a < b) ? c = 20 : c) = 30;
```

Because you can't "assign" to `(a > b) ? c = 10 : (a < b) ? c = 20 : c`, your compiler errors. You want:

```
(a > b) ? c = 10 : (a < b) ? c = 20 : (c = 30);
```

But it's really better to write:

```
c = (a > b) ? 10 : (a < b) ? 20 : 30;
```